# Show that the sequence $x_n = \sqrt{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt{n + 1}$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

already tried to do $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1$ or $x_{n+1}-x_n>0$ but I didn't get anything. any tips?

I want to use this to show the divergence. Only this step is missing from my demonstration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let
$$ f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x+1} $$
and then show $f'(x)>0$. It is not necessary to use this to show $\{x_n\}$ diverges. In fact $\sqrt{n+1}\le\frac12n$ for $n\ge3$ and hence
$$ x_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n+1}\ge n-\frac12n =\frac12n$$
and hence $\{x_n\}$ diverges.

Comment: Showing that the function is increasing does not prove that the sequence diverges.  For example: the function sqrt(x) is increasing but yet the sequence tends to 0, 1, or $i ($if $x_0 < 0)$.  However, if f(x) > x, then that would prove that the sequence diverges.

Comment: The OP's question is to show the sequence is increasing.

Comment: yes, i didn't use that as an argument.  but I use it as part of it.  in particular, I use it to argue that my sequence is unlimited.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I was thinking it was a recurrence relation.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: note that
$$
\begin{align}
x_n &=(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt{n+1}) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \sqrt{n+1}}
\\ & = \frac{n^2 + 1 - (n + 1)}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \sqrt{n+1}}
\\ & = \frac{n^2 - n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \sqrt{n+1}} \cdot \frac{1/n}{1/n}
\\ & = \frac{n - 1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac 1{n^2}} + \sqrt{\frac 1n + \frac 1{n^2}}}.
\end{align}
$$
From there, we can easily see that $x_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.